# Do i need to test material UI components?

Tags: reactjs, testing, material-ui, react-testing-library

It's my first project. Is it good to unit and integration test Material UI's component (Data Grid,etc ) component?

Data grid has many features such filtering, sorting, editable and multi filtering

Comment: The library has tests https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/next/packages/material-ui but any logic you build around the components you should probably focus on testing instead.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky It means no bother to test . and I should test only my own extra logic applied to the components !

Comment: Yeah start with that